# AngularJS controller code not being evaluated in IE9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9

Thanks for looking.

I have some AngularJS code that is running fine in all browsers EXCEPT for IE9.  IE8 even works fine, but not IE9.

For example, the breakpoint in the following screen grab will not be hit in IE9, though some regular JS code above it is hit:

[image]

Again, this works fine in IE8 even.  Odder still, there are no JavaScript errors produced.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else runs into this frustrating issue, for me the answer was this:

Create your opening `body` tag like this:

```
<body xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app">
```

Then, just before your closing `body` tag, place this `script`:

```
 <script>
         (function () {

                 angular.module('app');

                 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                     angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
                 });                

         })();
        </script>
```

I have theories as to why this works, but in truth I am not certain.  Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Oh man! great great great, i was having problem with IE8/IE9 controller binding and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @maverickosama92--So glad it helped you!  Its these moments that make Stack Overflow great!

Comment: Man , youre awesome